# From PDF document to JPEG images in AppleScript

Tags: macos, pdf, applescript

How can I extract JPEG images from a PDF file using AppleScript? Is there a command such as `saveJpegFromPage(PDFstream, numberOfPage)`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Short answer:** you don’t in straight AppleScript (because there isn’t such a command) – but you can sidestep the issue by using the *poppler* shell utility package inside AppleScript.

**Long answer:** AppleScript’s default abilities (as defined by *Standard Additions*) and the dictionaries provided by the OS and its included applications do not include PDF processing. Tellingly, OS X’ very own PDF application, *Preview.app*, was not even scriptable for most of its existence.

As to third party apps, [Adobe’s *Acrobat X Pro*](https://www.adobe.com/acrobat/acrobat-pro.html) might be able to do this (I can’t check, as the price tag is altogether too hefty for me, and [there is no trial version for OS X](https://www.adobe.com/acrobat/free-trial-download.html)), but of the two best known affordable scriptable third party PDF apps, [*Skim*](https://skim-app.sourceforge.io/) and [*PDFPen*](https://pdfpen.com/pdfpen/), neither’s AS dictionary contains commands for processing images in PDF files.

However, as is often the case, the shell provides an alternative. The *xpdf* package contains a utility called `pdfimages` which will do what you are after. The command

```
pdfimages -j -f 1 -l 1 "/path/to/my file.pdf" "/path/to/folder for images"
```

will save all images on page 1 of `/path/to/my file.pdf` to the folder `/path/to/folder for images` in JPEG format (refer to `man pdfimages` for an explanation of all options). Note this is taken from [*poppler*](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/)’s `pdfimages` man page, which is an evolution of [the original *xpdf* package](https://web.archive.org/web/20170810060643/http://www.foolabs.com:80/xpdf/). Your best bet for installing *poppler* probably is the [*homebrew* package manager](https://brew.sh/) (`brew install poppler`).

Once you have the package on your system, all you have to do to use its abilities inside AppleScript is wrap it in a `do shell script` command, along the lines of

```
do shell script "'path/to/pdfimages' -j -f " & pageNum & " -l " & pageNum & " '" & (POSIX path of myPDF) & "' '" & (POSIX path of targetFolder) & "'"
```

and you should be set.

Comment: A really exhaustive answer. Your cleared many doubts of mine. Thank you very much.